# Muli-Input Muli-output diagram with feedforward from input

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like get some help with this. This is the 2nd time I use Tikz and I'm trying to draw the following in latex.
[image]. I started with the script in [Drawing a multiple input - multiple output system diagram with TiKz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299693/drawing-a-multiple-input-multiple-output-system-diagram-with-tikz) 
I tried to look up how to modify it to look like the one I want but no success. I would appreciate your help with this.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 22mm]
\node (adc) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {ADC};
\coordinate[above left = of adc.west]   (a1);
\coordinate[below = of a1]              (a2);
\coordinate[below = of a2]              (a3);
\coordinate[above right= 8mm and 22mm of adc.east]  (b1);
\coordinate[above right = of adc.east]   (A1);
\coordinate[below = of A1]              (A2);
\coordinate[below = of A2]              (A3);
\coordinate[above left= 8mm and 22mm of adc.west]  (b2);
\foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {X,Y,Z}
\draw[-latex']  (a\xi) node[left] {\i} -- (a\xi-| adc.west);
\foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {A,B,C}
\draw[-latex']  (A\xi-| adc.east) -- (A\xi) node[right] {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

****** UPDATE
Can someone help me with aligning the input and the output arrows in the code below (from the answer below by @marmot). Thank you

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

    \begin{document}
        \tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156990/121799
            dots/.style args={#1per #2}{%
                line cap=round,
                dash pattern=on 0 off #2/#1
            }
        }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
    \node (adc) [draw,minimum size=24mm]at (0,0) {ADC} ;
    \coordinate[right=3.5cm of adc] (r);
    \coordinate[below=1cm of adc] (b);
    \foreach \X/\Z [count=\Y] in {0.1/1,0.7/2,1.8/n}
    {
        \node[below left=\X*1cm and 2cm of adc.north west] (y\Y) {$x_\Z$};
        \draw[->] (y\Y) -- (y\Y-|adc.west) coordinate[pos=\Y/4] (aux\Y);
        \node[draw,below right=\X*1cm and {(2.5-\X)*1cm} of adc.north east,circle,inner sep=3pt] (y'\Y) {};
        %   \node[below left=\Y*1cm and 2cm of adc.north west] (y'\Y) {$\hat{x}_\Z$};
        %   \draw[->] (y'\Y-|adc.east) -- (y'\Y);
        \draw[->] (y'\Y-|adc.east)node[above right]{$\hat{x}_\Z$} --   (y'\Y);
        \draw[->] (y'\Y) -- (y'\Y-|r) node[right]{$r_\Z$};
        \draw[->] (aux\Y) |- ([yshift={(-1+\Y*0.5)*1cm}]b) -| (y'\Y);
    }
    \draw[very thick,dots={6 per 1cm}] ([yshift=1mm]aux3) -- ([yshift=-1mm]aux2 -| aux3);
    \draw[very thick,dots={6 per 1cm}] ([yshift=1mm]y'3.north) -- ([yshift=-1mm]y'2 -| y'3);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `arrows` library has been superseded by `arrows.meta`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156990/121799
  dots/.style args={#1per #2}{%
    line cap=round,
    dash pattern=on 0 off #2/#1
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
\node (adc) [draw,minimum size=24mm]at (0,0) {ADC} ;
\coordinate[right=4cm of adc] (r);
\coordinate[below=1cm of adc] (b);
\foreach \X/\Z [count=\Y] in {0.1/1,0.5/2,1.8/n}
{\node[below left=\X*1cm and 2cm of adc.north west] (y\Y) {$y_\Z$};
\draw[->] (y\Y) -- (y\Y-|adc.west) coordinate[pos=\Y/4] (aux\Y);
\node[draw,below right=\X*1cm and {(2.5-\X)*1cm} of adc.north east,circle,inner sep=3pt] (y'\Y) {};
\draw[->] (y'\Y-|adc.east) --  node[pos=0.5,above]{$\widehat{y}_\Y$} (y'\Y);
\draw[->] (y'\Y) -- (y'\Y-|r) node[right]{$r_\Z'$};
\draw[->] (aux\Y) |- ([yshift={(-1+\Y*0.5)*1cm}]b) -| (y'\Y);
}
\draw[very thick,dots={6 per 1cm}] ([yshift=1mm]aux3) -- ([yshift=-1mm]aux2 -| aux3);
\draw[very thick,dots={6 per 1cm}] ([yshift=1mm]y'3.north) -- ([yshift=-1mm]y'2 -| y'3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]